# Excel - Conditional Formatting to highlight if cell value equals and another cell value is before date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

I'm trying to make a conditional formatting formula to highlight the row if EmployeeStatus in Column I equals "Terminated" and if EmployeeStatusDate in column J is before 2/1/2019. Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
=IF(AND(I3="Terminated", J3<""), "2/1/2019", "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
=AND($I1="Terminated", $J1<>"", $J1<DATE(2019,2,1))
```

the cell reference must be the top row of the `Applies to:` Range

Comment: Still seems to be highlighting active status' and not all dates before 2/1/2019

Comment: please edit your op to include a screen grab of the CF manager for those cells

Comment: @CameronCole see update, if  it is still off then check the data.